# Using the `fixed` keyword with `IntPtr.ToPointer`

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, garbage-collection, keyword

I am writing image processing methods and have some confusion about fixed pointers in an unsafe context. Generally we fix pointers using the `fixed` keyword in conjunction with the `addressof` operator `&`.

```
fixed (int* p = &pt.x) // Common example does not seem to apply in my case.
```

When using `Bitmap.LockBits`, we are given an `IntPtr` returned by `BitmapData.Scan0`.

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 600))
{
    var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Error: You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression.
    fixed (void* p = data.Scan0.ToPointer()) {...}

    // Works fine but does [byte* p] remain fixed?
    byte* p = (byte*) data.Scan0.ToPointer();

    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

The question is, do we NEED to use the fixed keyword in this context? If not, how does `byte* p` not get affected by the GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `fixed` here. Which is fortunate, since the compiler's not going to let you use it anyway. :)

The call to the `LockBits()` method is what pins the memory block. That's what's meant in the documentation when it says that the method:

> Locks a Bitmap into system memory

Calling `UnlockBits()` unpins it later (which is why you should put that call in a `finally` block).